# How to make WCF data interface serializable

Tags: wcf, interface

I have a WCF service and one method accepts an interface IValidationDictionary when calling the service I need to access the interface but the VS generated proxy class shows the interface as an object. I tried to add data attributes to the interface but that is not allowed.

Thanks in advance.

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    private IValidationDictionary validatonDictionary;

    private IUserAppService userAppService;

    public UserService(IUserAppService userAppService)
    {
        this.userAppService = userAppService;
    }

    public void SetValidation(IValidationDictionary validationDictionary)
    {
        this.validatonDictionary = validationDictionary;
    }

    public UserDTO GetUser(int id)
    {
        return this.userAppService.GetUser(id);
    }
}

public interface IValidationDictionary
{
    void AddError(string key, string errorMessage);

    bool IsValid();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interfaces can not be serialize, but you can return any object which implements that interface.

Comment: Thats what I thought but there was a reason to use the interface as I wanted to decouple the service framework from the MVC app. The service framework needs no knowledge of the implementation. Is the only way to create a concrete class?